# Па́влович чи Павло́вич

Tags: наголос

У імені [Павло́](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE) наголос на другий склад. А як правильно робити наголос по батькові Па́влович чи Павло́вич?

[Наголошення чоловічих імен на -о](http://kulturamovy.univ.kiev.ua/KM/pdfs/Magazine41-10.pdf) вказує, що потрібно робити наголос на перший склад Па́влович. Інших джерел підтвердження чи спростування даної інформації не знайшла.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Словник наголосів української мови](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) надає лише один варіант наголосу в іменнику Павлович:

> відмінок  однина  множина
>
> називний  Па́влович   Па́вловичі
>
> родовий   Па́вловича  Па́вловичів
>
> давальний Па́вловичу, Па́вловичеві    Па́вловичам
>
> знахідний Па́вловича  Па́вловичів
>
> орудний   Па́вловичем Па́вловичами
>
> місцевий  на/у Па́вловичу, Па́вловичі, Па́вловичеві   на/у Па́вловичах
>
> кличний   Па́вловичу  Па́вловичі

Це пов'язано з історичним розвитком мови. В [дослідженні](http://kulturamovy.univ.kiev.ua/KM/pdfs/Magazine41-10.pdf) В. Г. СКЛЯРЕНКО
"НАГОЛОШЕННЯ ЧОЛОВІЧИХ ІМЕН НА -О В МИНУЛОМУ І ТЕПЕР" докладно відображено зміни, що призвели до такого наголошення.

> У сучасній українській літературній мові двоскладові чоловічі імена на -о 
>   характеризуються флективним наголосом (Петро́, Павло́, Дмитро́,
>   Карпо́) або подвійним — кореневим і флективним (Ма́рко́), а
>   трискладові імена на -о вживаються з наголосом на другому складі
>   кореня (Миха́йло, Самі́йло, Ману́йло, Дани́ло, Гаври́ло, Кири́ло та
>   ін.). У минулому наголошення всіх названих двоскладових імен, за
>   винятком Петро, було іншим. Давні українські пам’ятки послідовно
>   засвідчують флективну акцентуацію імені Петр, але кореневу імен Павел,
>   Дімитр, Карп, Марко. Імена по батькові Па́влович, Дми́трович,
>   Ка́рпович, Ма́ркович, але
>   Петро́вич, теж свідчать, що на час виникнення названих імен по
>   батькові імена Павел, Дімитр, Карп, Марко вживалися з кореневим
>   наголосом, а ім’я Петр — з флективним.